# How to add ECS attributes to an instance using terraform

Tags: terraform

I heavily use [ECS Attributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/put-attributes.html) on our containerized infrastructure. I couldn't find terraform docs to achieve this. Do I need to execute aws cli commands manually to apply those attributes after creating the infrastructure?

Comment: Just realised after searching and answering this that you cross posted it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919689/how-to-add-ecs-attributes-to-an-instance-using-terraform. Please state when you are cross posting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform docs are pretty comprehensive, so if it’s not in the docs it’s probably not implemented yet.

However, they’re very responsive to feature requests posted as GitHub issues, particularly those that indicate that the feature is available via the AWS CLI (or more specifically, the AWS Go SDK). In my experience, feature requests I’ve raised have usually been available in a new AWS provider release within a month or so.

I’d suggest doing up a new issue here:
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues

(I did do a quick search to see if ECS attributes have been raised before and couldn’t see any at a quick glance, but you may like to as well!)

Answer (score 1):

In Terraform, **value_specs** are a way of injecting extra key/value pairs into the create request to help with random vendor-specific data. Anyhow this is a workaround option and also it works well with OpenStack provider but I haven't tried with AWS. Could you please try this approach and post your comments.

```
value_specs {   
      Attrkey = AttrValue 
}
```

Comment: I think this is specific to the OpenStack provider, at least, I haven’t come across it in the AWS provider and one of the first results for ‘Terraform value_specs’ is https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/openstack/r/dns_recordset_v2.html